# How do I associate a MatPaginator with a MatTable taking a declarative data source exclusively in the template?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, angular-material-paginator

I am attempting to associate a `MatPaginator` with a `MatTable` who's dataSource input property is simply declared in the template, and not subscribed to from within the component itself.  For example:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="allData$ | async" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Normally, I would associate the paginator with the data source in the component like so:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set paginator(paginator: MatPaginator) {
    if (paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator = paginator;
    }
  }
  dataSource;
  displayedColumns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'ip_address'];

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this will not work with the former method, as we are not actually creating a new datasource directly, and have no way to associate the data source and is automatically subscribed declarative via the `async` pipe.

Here is a StackBlitz showing the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ebddd6?file=src/app/app.component.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't make it `MatTableDataSource` though not subscribing to it in the component. We just set the data inside `map` and return a `MatTableDataSource`, that way you can attach the paginator to it. For the `ViewChild` matpaginator we need to set `static: true` so that we can access it immediately, so I would do:

```ts
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

allData$ = this.appService.getData().pipe(
  map((data) => {
    let dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    return dataSource;
  })
);
```

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgvz19?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This looks good--it's far more simple than I realized, as I was missing that `{ static: true }` on the `ViewChild`.

Comment: Ah yes, static: true can be handy sometimes, in cases like this :)

Answer (score 1):

A mat-paginator can be used "standalone" or when you has a MatTableDataSource object. The property "datasource" of a mat-table can be: an array, an observable or a MatTableDataSource.

To use standalone, you can use a template reference variable "pag" and a variable "length"

```
<mat-paginator #pag [length]="length"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
  showFirstLastButtons>
</mat-paginator>
```

Then use |slice in the way

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="allData$|async 
           |slice:pag.pageIndex*pag.pageSize:
                  (pag.pageIndex+1)*pag.pageSize" 
    class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

The last piece of the jigsaw is use pipe tap to get the length of the array

```
  allData$ = this.appService.getData().pipe(
    tap((res:any[])=>{
      this.length=res.length
    }))
```

To avoid the error "AfterChecked" you can asign to the variable allData$ in a ngOnInit enclosed in a setTimeOut

```
   ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.allData$ = this.appService.getData().pipe(
        tap((res:any[])=>{
          this.length=res.length
        }))
      })
    }
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cq2fwh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)