# Angular add paginator to the table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have one mat-table like this: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/table-dynamic-array-data-example.ts . I'm trying to add pagination for it. The problem is that the dataSource is not like here: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/table-pagination-example.ts

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA); //not like this
```

Instead is like this: dataSource: tableElement[];

I'm trying this: `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator` But it's telling me that Property 'paginator' does not exist on type 'tableElement[]'.  (tableElement beeing a type create by me). How could I add paginator to this kind of table?

Comment: Seems like your link will redirect to StackBlitz home page. As the example mentions to use `MatTableDataSource`, why not to use it? While to set the data to mat-table dataSource, `this.dataSource.data = /* Your Data Array */;`

Comment: Thanks! Just used this some minutes ago and you're right, it's working! This is the answer :)

Comment: To make `this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator`, the "dataSource", should be a **MatTableDataSource** (see the answer of @denisiulian). If you want to use an array as dataSource, you need use the mat-paginator as "standalone", see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355659/how-do-i-associate-a-matpaginator-with-a-mattable-taking-a-declarative-data-sour/70356428#70356428)

Answer (score 0):

`dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<tableElement>([]); //declaration`

How to update data:

```
this.dataSource.data = this.yourData;
```